# How do I prevent Chrome bookmark dropdown lists from vanishing after I've used them?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I compile and organise a lot of bookmarks. My Chrome bookmarks menu bar has many folders and subfolders. Some organisation of their contents involves moving items from place to place, for example moving bookmarks from one subfolder to another.

Immediately after I move a bookmark to a new place the dropdown snaps shut.  This means I sometimes have to navigate back to where I was several times in a row to move several bookmarks from one place to another.

Is there a setting which prevents Chrome dropdown bookmark folders from snapping shut immediately after they are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there's no option for that. I had to deal with this when I moved to Chrome (I used Maxthon before which was based on IE). Currently, I just use groups or manually open each bookmark I want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that and it has been this way since chrome was released. (There is even an issue posted on the chromium bug tracker from 2008 [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2469))

As a workaround, you can drag and drop in the bookmark manager instead (shortcut Ctrl+Shift+O on Windows/Linux or ⌘ + Option + b on Mac).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems to be yet another of those issues the public are frustrated by but the developer doesn't care about. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer, although I'm told my vote is recorded.